# get <img> tag from @imagecreatefromjpeg?

Tags: php, jquery, image

I am writing text over image using PHP.I am easily creating new image from current image and writing text over it using PHP.But I also want that when I click on Apply Changes then move this new image to my directory (move_uploaded_file) and replace the current image with the new image and new image name must be the same of the previous image because I am downloading it using PHP.

Here is my code which I am using to wrote text over it.

**HTML code :**

```
     <img id="image" src="<?php echo "upload_pic/" . $_FILES["image_file"]["name"]; ?>" alt="your_image" />
        <input type="button" name="save_image" id="save_image" value="Save Image" />
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_image_name" name="hidden_image_name" value="<?php echo $_FILES["image_file"]["name"]; ?>" />
```

**jQuery Code :**

```
jQuery('#save_image').click(function(){
        var image_name = jQuery('#hidden_image_name').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
        url:'text_image.php',
        data:'file='+image_name,
        type:'get',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    });
```

**text_image.php**

```
<?php

$file = 'upload_pic/'.$_GET['file'];

/*** set the header for the image ***/
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

    /*** specify an image and text ***/
    $im = writeToImage($file, 'PHPRO rules again');
    //echo $im;
    /*** spit the image out the other end ***/
    imagejpeg($im);

    /**
     *
     * @Write text to an existing image
     *
     * @Author Kevin Waterson
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param string The image path
     *
     * @param string The text string
     *
     * @return resource
     *
     */
    function writeToImage($imagefile, $text){
    /*** make sure the file exists ***/
    if(file_exists($imagefile))
        {    
        /*** create image ***/
        $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imagefile);

        /*** create the text color ***/
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

        /*** splatter the image with text ***/
        imagestring($im, 6, 25, 150,  "$text", $text_color);
        }
    else
        {
        /*** if the file does not exist we will create our own image ***/
        /*** Create a black image ***/
        $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30); /* Create a black image */

        /*** the background color ***/
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

        /*** the text color ***/
        $tc  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

        /*** a little rectangle ***/
        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

        /*** output and error message ***/
        imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, "Error loading $imagefile", $tc);
        }

    return $im;
    }
?>
```

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: I checked response it is very complicated �����JFIF���������>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality
���C�  

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342���C   

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222�����"�������������� 
�������}�!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�

Comment: that's not "complicated", that's just what a jpeg image looks like when you view it in text mode.

Comment: also, beware of using `$_FILES["image_file"]["name"]` -- since the `name` of the file is determined by the client, it's possible for it to be used as an attack vector. eg If it contains slashes, your code could end up loading a different file to the one you expect. You should make sure you sanitise it before use, or just don't use it at all (ie make up your own names for uploaded files).

Comment: `$file = 'upload_pic/'.$_GET['file'];` - very unsecure

Answer (score 1):

You want to reload the IMG source upon change. So what you need to do is to replace the `SRC=` value of the IMG tag, by adding a dummy query to avoid caching:

```
jQuery('#save_image').click(function(){
    var image_name = jQuery('#hidden_image_name').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url:'text_image.php',
    data:'file='+image_name,
    type:'get',
    success:function(data){
        jQuery('#image').attr('src', jQuery('#image')
            .attr('src')+'?'+Math.random());
    }
});
});
```

The PHP script needs output nothing, just rewrite the image file

```
<?php

    $file = 'upload_pic/'.$_GET['file'];
    $im = writeToImage($file, 'PHPRO rules again');

    imageJPEG($im, $file, 95); // 95% quality

    die();

    ...
?>
```

You may want to output a JSON stating 'success' or 'failure', though, just in case.

You also want to check that `$_GET['file']` is a valid, accessible, allowed, image. For example you might force the file to be a basename:

```
    $file = 'upload_pic/'.basename($_GET['file']);
    if (!file_exists($file))
         // ...no such file...
    if (false === getImageSize($file))
         // ...doesn't look like an image...
    // etc.
```

## Another way

If you want to keep both original and 'captioned' image, you need to [create a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648882/generating-unique-filename), and therefore output the new name so that jQuery can replace the SRC attribute.

For example:

```
    $new = 'upload_pic/'.uniqid().'.jpg';

    ...create the file and put $im into it, as above...

    Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
    die(json_serialize(array("src" => $new)));
    // Or if you don't want json_serialize (BUT THEN $new may only contain printable ASCII-7 characters that need no escaping. "[a-z][0-9]-_." if you want to be sure).
    die("{\"src\":\"{$new}\"}");
```

in jQuery, `data` will now contain `$new`, so:

```
    success:function(data){
        jQuery('#image').attr('src', data.src);
    }
```

(in the page, you may need to update other fields if you want to re-caption an already-captioned image).

Comment: What happens if you invoke the PHP script from the browser (i.e. not through AJAX) with the same `file=` parameter value? That should give some hint on what's going wrong.

Comment: @iserni First way is working fine ... :) thanks for it but I want to kepp both the files original and new so I am using second way but in second way new image is creating but this image is coming blank.


I just change this code in **text_image.php** 

`$unique_id = rand();
$file = 'upload_pic/'.$unique_id.$_GET['file'];` 

and in main file this code

`jQuery('#image').attr('src', data);`

Comment: It could be a path problem. In the `success` function, try putting `alert(data)` to see whether the file name gets received correctly. If it does, verify that the file on disk exists and is created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would send a XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) with jQuery, because `window.location.href='text_image.php?file='+image_name;`
isn't save. The user could go back in the browser history and visit this site again.

Also I think you haven't change the file name.
 `move_uploaded_file($im,"upload_pic/angelina.jpg");`

A small tip: Don't use the @ operator before functions! It's a performance killer.

Comment: This is just code of text writing which I was checking. I will do this using AJAX.

Comment: how to move this file because what will be the name of this newly created file and what will be the tmp_name